# Class-like behavior Javascript

Tags: javascript, class

So I have this Javascript function (class):

```
function Test() {
    this.a = function() { return 'hello'; }
    this.b = function() { alert(this.a()); }
    window.onload = this.b;
}
test = new Test();
```

The code does not work, because the function this.b on window load becomes a global function (outside of the Test function/class) where this.a does not exist.

Something like this:

```
function Test() {
    this.a = function() { return 'hello'; }
    this.b = function() { alert(test.a()); } // changed this to test
    window.onload = this.b;
}
test = new Test();
```

does work, but it assumes I know which variable holds the Test function/class which loses the functionality of creating multiple classes.

What is the best solution to maintain this approach (using this pointers inside function/class) and get the wanted result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) -- especially see the part *Common problem: Using object methods as callbacks / event handlers*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, it has nothing to do with scope and everything to do with context.

See, when an event handler is called, `this` is set to whatever element the event is bound to. In this case, `this` is `window`.

Try something like this:

```
function Test() {
    var self = this;
    self.a = function() {return 'hello';};
    self.b = function() {alert(self.a());};
    window.onload = self.b;
}
```

By "saving" the context to a variable `self`, you avoid context problems.

Comment: All answers did the job, upvoted. Chose yours as answer for explaining the binding of this.

Answer (score 3):

in your code `this` refers to the local function `function() { alert(this.a()); }`, if you want to refer to the "class scope" you have to store a refence to the class :

```
function Test() {
    var localTest = this;
    this.a = function() { return 'hello'; }
    this.b = function() { alert(localTest.a()); }
    window.onload = this.b;
}
test = new Test();
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by *"in your code this refers to the local `function function() { alert(this.a()); }`"* (what refers to the function? Did you mean `this`?), but I think it's wrong.

Comment: the this refers to local context, not the class context, so when you call the function, the object calling the funcion has the this scope, so you have to store a reference to the outern class

Comment: Yeah, that makes more sense (but you really should format `this` as code). But that's not what you have written in your answer. You wrote it so that it can be easily understood as that `this` refers to `function() {...}` (which would be wrong).

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
window.onload = this.b.bind(this)
```

When you write `someObj.func` in javascript, the resulting reference has no idea of `someObj`. Therefore, if you need the correct `this` in `func`, you have to provide it explicitly.

This can be done by closing `this` in the `func`'s parent scope, as other answers suggest, but [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is more transparent in my opinion.

Comment: `.bind()` is not cross-browser, unfortunately.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol this is why i didn't knew about that. but when it will be fully supported will be nice. Support table at the end of the page linked [Mozilla docs about bind function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: No, but there are polyfills available. Have a look at the MDN documentation.